# chpasswd apply changes in the chroot directory

Tags: debian, arch-linux, chroot, debootstrap

I have `debootstraped` version of `wheezy` on my `Archlinux` machine and would like to change it's `root` password:

```
echo "root:toor" | chpasswd --root /home/containers/wheezy/
```

However I get an error:

```
chpasswd: PAM: Permission denied
```

Works fine on my local `root` user (without `--root` option).

The `man` page clearly states the following:

> -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
>   Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the   configuration files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.

So what am I doing wrong? And how does `PAM` get involved anyway? Other methods to do this?

***EDIT***

```
# echo "root:toor" | sudo strace -f -efile,execve chpasswd --root /home/containers/wheezy/
```

Below is the output where `chpasswd` starts complaining.

```
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
chpasswd: PAM: Permission denied
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

***EDIT2***

I have found that the files `chpasswd` is expecting on the target container can be found for many other languages except *English*:

```
# find /usr/share/locale/ -iname '*Linux-PAM.mo*'
/usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
...
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
```

Note: `en_GB` which `chpasswd` is expecting might be equal to `uk` on the target container?..

I've tried to reinstall packages which seem to have required files:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libpam-runtime login locales locales-all
```

But that didn't help at all.

***EDIT3***

When I run `strace` on the target container it is not looking for these files:

```
# echo "root:toor2" | strace -f -e open chpasswd --root /
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/etc/pam.d/chpasswd", O_RDONLY)   = 3
open("/etc/pam.d/common-password", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_unix.so", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 5
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_deny.so", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_permit.so", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/etc/pam.d/other", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/etc/pam.d/common-auth", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/etc/pam.d/common-account", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/etc/pam.d/common-password", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/etc/pam.d/common-session", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/etc/.pwd.lock", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 4
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 4
open("/etc/nshadow", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY)           = 5
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 4
Process 7760 attached
Process 7759 suspended
Process 7759 resumed
Process 7760 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

***EDIT4***

Eventually I've run the same command on the same container on `Debian Jessie` and it **worked**.
The case is solved - `Wheezy` and `Archlinux` simply has different implementations of `chpasswd`.

I think the best portable workaround for this problem is as suggested by @Peter Cordes:

```
echo 'root:toor' | chroot /home/containers/wheezy/ /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Comment: And you're running that as root?  And the files in your chroot have normal ownership?

Comment: Yes, I run these commands as a `root` user and files/directories in the `chroot` dir are owned by the `root` user.

Comment: Maybe try `echo | sudo strace -f -efile,execve chpasswd --root /home/containers/wheezy/`?

Comment: Apparently the problem starts here: `open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: It's common to see a lot of attempts to open files that don't exist.  That's just opening the translations into British-English, in case there are any.  (en-GB, en-CA, etc. are very light on translations.  A couple programs might have colour instead of color in a translated string, but unfortunately a complete lack of lorries, bonnets, petrol, and mobiles.  Not to mention bangers and mash.)

Comment: Please see updated question. `chpasswd` gives up after not being able to find a few toys on the `PAM`/`locale` playground. I wonder which package might install required files on the base `debian` system?

Comment: @NarūnasK Great update to the question! A quick and dirty solution would be to bind mount your host's `/usr/share` into the chroot tree. That may not be what you want, though, in case your bootstrapped environment has special packages installed under that subtree.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `chroot` into your installation?

```
chroot /home/containers/wheezy
passwd root
```

Comment: because this is executed in the script

Comment: does `echo ... | chroot /home/containers/wheezy chpasswd` work?

Comment: Nope, but `echo 'root:toor' | chroot /home/containers/wheezy/ /usr/sbin/chpasswd` did :) When I `chroot` my `$PATH` environment variable lacks `/bin` so I had to use full paths... Hence your answer shows a good workaround, but it would be good to know why the original line didn't work...

Comment: I know that I'm late to the party, but I still don't understand how the `--root` argument works. It doesn't appear to work as described in the manpage. Is this a bug in chpasswd?